# Why doesn't angular render my field component?

Tags: angular

I have a BoxComponent that has only one field, an array of numbers. The selector for this Component is `app-box`

`box.component.html`

```
<p>
    <span *ngFor="let num of cards">Number is {{num}}</span>
</p>
```

`box.component.ts`

```
export class BoxComponent {

  cards: number[] = [];

  top_up(val: number) {
    this.cards.push(val);
  }

}
```

In its parent AppComponent, I added a single field that stores a BoxComponent object.

`app.component.html`

```
<app-box></app-box>
<button (click)="push()">Top-up</button>
```

`app.component.ts`

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'test';
  box: BoxComponent = new BoxComponent();

  push() {
    this.box.top_up(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
  }
}
```

I wish to make the click in the appcomponent template to modify the contents of `app-box`.
However angular does not update the app-box when the button is clicked. I somehow was able to confirm that the field box of appcomponent actually gets updated, the change just doesn't show in the browser. Based on this I have concluded that the `app-box` tag creates a different `BoxComponent` rather than use the one I have created within the AppComponent class.

Am I right? How do I make angular render my box and respond to changes I make to it from the AppComponent click event?

Edit: I have simplified the problem to its simplest form.

Comment: where is the code for adding or removing other cards?

Comment: I have updated the question to include those parts. I didn't think they were relevant to the question. I am a beginner to angular you see.

Comment: I have simplified the problem the previous one was too verbose but this equally represents the exact same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the app component to :

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'test';
  @ViewChild('bComponent') boxComponent!: BoxComponent;

  push() {
    this.boxComponent.top_up(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
  }
}
```

and it's html to :

```
<app-box #bComponent></app-box>
<button (click)="push()">Top-up</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @Vahid18u. This works perfectly for this scenario, what if the field was an array of BoxComponent objects instead of just one?

Comment: I guess @ViewChildren might help.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the "return" keyword in the "add_card" function.

> card.ts

```
export class Card {
  suit: number | undefined;
  rank: number | undefined;

  constructor(suit: number, rank: number) {
    this.suit = suit;
    this.rank = rank;
  }
}
```

> player.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Card } from '../card';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-player',
  templateUrl: './player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./player.component.css'],
})
export class PlayerComponent {
  cards: Card[] = [];

  constructor() {
    this.cards = [new Card(2, 4), new Card(3, 7)];
  }

  add_card() {
   return this.cards.push(new Card(2, 4));
  }
}
```

> player.component.html

```
<div class="card-container">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="card" *ngFor="let card of cards">
            <span>suit {{card.suit}}</span>
            <span>rank {{card.rank}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button (click)="add_card()">Add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: So I have tried it but it hasn't changed the behavior of the application.

Comment: I have edited and added a new button

Comment: basically when I call the deal on each of the players from the app.component.ts, the change is not renderd but it is rendered if I call it from player.component.html

Comment: I have simplified the problem the previous one was too verbose but this equally represents the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way in your App component

```
@ViewChild(BoxComponent)BoxComponentRef:BoxComponent;
push()
{
this.BoxComponentRef.top_up(Math.floor(Math.random());
}
```